# Java Regex to verify sql query string contains SELECT and LIMIT

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex expression for validating if a sql query in the form of a string begins with a SELECT and ends with a LIMIT followed by a number. Of course, this needs to be case insensitive and should be able to ignore preceding and trailing whitespaces.

```
Valid String:
1. select * from table where col='anything' limit 10
2. SELECT * from table where col='anything' LIMIT 10

Invalid String:
1. select * from table where col='anything'
2. SELECT * from table where col='anything'
```

I have tried the following, but it is not matching for any case and printing false for all four cases:

```
public class Main {

    private static final String  regex   = "^SELECT(?:[^;']|(?:'[^']+'))+ LIMIT + \\d+;\\s*$";
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private static boolean matchesPattern(String query) {
        return pattern.matcher(query).matches();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] queries = {
                "select * from table where col='anything'",             // should print false, as no limit condition
                "select * from table where col='anything' limit 10",    // should print true
                "SELECT * from table where col='anything'",             // should print false, as no limit condition
                "SELECT * from table where col='anything' LIMIT 10"     // should print true
        };

        for (String query: queries){
            System.out.println(matchesPattern(query));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really a pro in regex, but I think you should remove the + before and after LIMIT. they mean 'one or more times'.

Comment: Can't `'` be escaped in the '...' string? BTW, you just need to make `;` optional and remove the space before `\\d+` : [`^SELECT(?:[^;']|(?:'[^']+'))+ LIMIT +\d+;?\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/SDRX95/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a fix for the current pattern is to remove a space before `\\d+` and make the `;` optional by adding a `?` quantifier after it. Use

```
String regex = "^SELECT(?:[^;']|(?:'[^']+'))+ LIMIT +\\d+;?\\s*$";
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDRX95/1/).

In the `LIMIT + \\d+` part matches 2 or more spaces after `LIMIT` and the regex will fail to match anything if there is just 1 space.

None of the correct samples ends with `;` thus either remove it or make optional.

Note that `'...'` may contain escape single quotes, you will need to adjust the pattern. If they are escaped with a single quote use `'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'` instead of `'[^']+'` in your pattern.

Comment: Added the pattern to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex isn't right.
For your problem something like that is suitable:

```
"^(SELECT|select).*(LIMIT|limit) (\\d+);$"
```

Keep in mind that in your test you dont have a `;` at the end of your queries, so they will never return true.